# Android: TabLayout not showing any tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, androiddesignsupport

First time working with `com.android.support:design:23.1.1`, and having some issues getting TabLayout to work.

My app is basically set up as such:

- One main activity called LandingActivity which has a DrawerLayout with menu items in it.
- When selecting a menu item, I load different Fragments into a FrameLayout in the LandingActivity.
- Some of the loaded Fragments should show tabs at the top, some shouldn't.

My issue is, on the Fragment which is supposed to show tabs at the top, it has extra space in the nav bar like it should have tabs there, but nothing shows.

Code:

activity_landing.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
<!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

LandingActivity where I load the fragments:

```
 public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
    // position
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.drawer_home:
            fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.drawer_customize:
            fragment = CustomizeFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
```

home_fragment.xml (one which has tabs)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
   />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>
```

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static HomeFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle(); alreadySelectedFollowingInfo);

    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public HomeFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("One"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Two"));
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter
            (getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                BlogFragment tab1 = BlogFragment.newInstance();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TrendingFragment tab2 = TrendingFragment.newInstance();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

}

Might not be relevant, but tool_bar.xml used in activity_landing.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
```

That's about all I've got. Can't figure out what's going on.

[image: What it looks like now]

**EDIT:**

New code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



    return v;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(BlogFragment.newInstance(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(TrendingFragment.newInstance(), "TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

in your `onCreateView` means that you return a newly inflated home fragment without any of your initialization code.

You should be returning the view that you created at the beginning of `onCreateView`:

```
return v;
```

---

Sample PagerAdapter that provides tab titles:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

And so, your refactored onCreateView code would be something like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(BlogFragment.newInstance(), "One");
    adapter.addFragment(TrendingFragment.newInstance(), "Two");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I could have continued to look at this code all night and probably wouldn't have realized that mistake. Thanks for the second pair of eyes!

Comment: On second thought, I think there may still be an issue. I can't get it to show the text at all. I have the indicator but no text is showing.

Comment: If you examine the code in `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` you will see that it erases the tabs and sets the title supplied by the ViewPager's `getAdapter().getPageTitle()`. Since you didn't implement this, your tabs will be blank. This method is meant to be a convenience method that will set the tab titles and all the listeners, you're doing that yourself, so you don't need to do that. Alternatively, you could fully implement your ViewPager and use the convenience method.

Comment: I actually did just that but I have the same results. I'll edit my OP to include my new code. I debug it and everything seems fine. I see it go into getPageTitle and it pulls the correct title.

Comment: Can you replace your adapter with mine and use the `setupWithViewPager` convenience method.

Comment: I see in TabLayout.java the setText method has  mText = text;
            if (mPosition >= 0) {
                mParent.updateTab(mPosition);
            }. For me mPosition is always -1. I think this is the issue, because it never calles updateTab.

Comment: There's an issue with the design library with TabLayout in a fragment. v23.0.0 fixed it, but if you are using an earlier version, you should be doing a post.

Comment: I'm using com.android.support:design:23.1.1, but I've tried with and without the post.

Comment: So what are you getting now? The tabs work, but no text?

Comment: Yes I have tabs, I can switch between Fragments, I see the indicator scrolling, but there's just no Text at all.

Comment: Unless you want to work on it some more, I think I'm just going to use a 3rd part library https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip. Very simple. Thanks for your help I'll accept this answer in the morning.

Comment: .post method does it

Answer (score 0):

Return your initialized infleted view while you are returning

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

while you should return view v from first line of onCreateView

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

Comment: Thanks but I got that from karaokyo. My issue now is 2 tabs show, but they have no Text on them.